# Angular $routeProvider infinite routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

In my app.ts I have this defined

```
angular.module('app').config([
    '$routeProvider', 
    function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/Home', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/HomeView'
        })
        .when('/DashboardView/:AppName', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/DashboardView'
        })
        .otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: '/Home' 
        });
}]);
```

The route works just fine for any AppName that I have defined in my DB. How do I limit the routes to just the AppNames I have defined. Currently it is accepting routes like "/DashboardView/blahblahblah"

Thanks for the help

Comment: you could validate :AppName at init of controller, and then, redirect to a error page.

Comment: ahh good point. Thank you. Let me write something up real quick

Comment: @MatthewBowman did it work?

Comment: haven't finished writting it yet. I'll post with an update as soon as i'm done

Comment: that actually worked. I wrote a little validate function that was able to recognize the AppName from the routeParameters that just returned a boolean value. If true you are allowed to go the the DashboardView. If false routes to a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Your **templateUrl** should have **.html** extension

```
.when('/Home', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/HomeView.html'
        })
        .when('/DashboardView/:AppName', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/DashboardView.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
```

Comment: i'm not sure how adding the html extension solves this issue. But I did try and this just prevent the page from even loading